# Priority Queue Sorting Objects Incorrectly (User-Defined Compare)

Tags: c++, priority-queue

I have a class `Customer` which has a member variable `arrivalTime`. I have defined a getter function `getArrivalTime()`. I am storing `Customer` in a priority queue, and have defined a custom predicate as follows:

```
class ArrivalQueueCompare
{
public:
    bool operator()(const Customer &a, const Customer &b)
    {
        return a.getArrivalTime() > b.getArrivalTime();
    }
};
```

The priority queue is declared as:

`std::priority_queue<Customer, std::vector<Customer>, ArrivalQueueCompare> arrivalQueue;`

When I push four `Customer` objects, `a0`, `a1`, `a2`, and `a3`, into the priority queue, with arrival times `20`, `0`, `50`, and `30` respectively, the priority queue seems to have stored them in the order `a1`-`a0`-`a2`-`a3`.

According to my predicate the order should be `a1`-`a0`-`a3`-`a2`, but the priority queue is storing them otherwise. Why might this be?

I have attached screenshots from Xcode's debugger screen as a proof: [Screenshot 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C1q5M.png) [Screenshot 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VmP52.png) [Screenshot 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9KELl.png) [Screenshot 4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0PSnU.png)

Update:

I am reading in lines from a file and creating `Customer` objects with:

```
 while (std::getline(file, line))
    {
        Customer newCustomer = createCustomerObject(line);

        arrivalQueue.push(newCustomer);
    }
```

The `createCustomerObject()` function just creates, and returns, a `Customer` object by initialising the member variables of `Customer` using `line`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `priority_queue` doesn't store the object in a sorted fashion. It only guarantees that the first element is the largest one (depending on your compare).

So, observing the objects stored in a non-ordered fashion in the storage vector is expected.

When you start popping the objects with `pop()`, you'll see the remaining objects get reordered.